# Convert Mutable list to a custom List of object

Tags: kotlin, coordinates

I am trying to convert a Mutable list to a custom list of objects to store Latitude and Longitude.

However, I am not sure if the conversion is correct

So the `Mutable List` is declared as such `val coordinateArray: MutableList<MutableList<Double>> = mutableListOf()`

And this is how I convert it

```
    val pointList: MutableList<Point> = ArrayList()
    for (i in coordinateArray.indices) {
        val point = Point(i.toDouble(), (i+1).toDouble())
        pointList.add(point)
    }

    val distance = 0.0001
    val bufferedPolygonList: List<Point> = AreaBuffer.buffer(pointList, distance)
```

The code above produces a list of buffered polygon coordinates.

On testing the above the coordinates are in infinities which is not correct.

Can you let me know if I am doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue with your solution is that you are inserting values that you are iteration on, not using them as indexes to get values from the `coordinateArray` list.

Here is its implementation

```
public val Collection<*>.indices: IntRange
    get() = 0..size - 1
```

Try to use something like the code above

```
val coordinateArray: MutableList<MutableList<Double>> = mutableListOf(
    mutableListOf(1.0, 2.0),
    mutableListOf(2.0, 3.0),
    mutableListOf(3.0, 4.0)
)
val pointList: MutableList<Point> = ArrayList()
for (i in coordinateArray.indices) {
    val point = Point(coordinateArray[i][0], coordinateArray[i][1])
    pointList.add(point)
}
```

Also, note that it's preferable to use immutable structures and also you could simplify the code by using `map` function

```
val coordinateArray: List<List<Double>> = listOf(
    listOf(1.0, 2.0),
    listOf(2.0, 3.0)
)
val pointList = coordinateArray.map { Point(it[0], it[1]) }
println(pointList)
```

Comment: Thanks fedden, that worked a treat. Can I ask in the code above `bufferedPolygonList` returns a List<Point> and I need to convert it back to `MutableList<MutableList<Double>>` can I use the `map` function?

Comment: Will it be something like this? `val newCoordinateArray = bufferedPolygonList.map { MutableList<MutableList<Double>>{ it[0], it[1] } }`

Comment: I’m glad it helped. Yes, you could do it with map. For this you will need to convert each point to mutableList in map function, and then convert result list to mutable list. Something like bufferedPolygonList.map { mutableListOf( it.x, it.y ) }.toMutableList() should do the trick 

Comment: Yep that worked a treat :)

Answer (score 1):

You're converting the Int *indices* to Doubles while completely ignoring the actual *contents* of `coordinateArray`. You need to retrieve those values by using the indices.

```
val pointList: MutableList<Point> = ArrayList()
for (i in coordinateArray.indices) {
    val point = Point(coordinateArray[i][0], coordinateArray[i][1])
    pointList.add(point)
}
```

Here are a couple of more succinct ways to do it:

```
val pointList = buildList<Point> {
    for (i in coordinateArray.indices) {
        val point = Point(coordinateArray[i][0], coordinateArray[i][1])
        add(point)
    }
}
```

```
val pointList = coordinateArray.map { Point(it[0], it[1]) }
```

Comment: All of my code above assumes an even number size of `coordinateArray`.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that your input is a 2D list, so an even size is irrelevant. I fixed the code above to account for that.